# Assign a set of vectors based on on a character vector (automating code)

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, purrr, r-glue

I want to do a series of assignments

```
rename2014 <- eas_dictionary$name2014
rename2015 <- eas_dictionary$name2015
rename2017 <- eas_dictionary$name2017

names(rename2014) <- eas_dictionary$true_name
names(rename2015) <- eas_dictionary$true_name
names(rename2017) <- eas_dictionary$true_name

eas_14 %<>% rename(all_of(rename2014))
eas_15 %<>% rename(all_of(rename2015))
eas_17 %<>% rename(all_of(rename2017))
```

(`eas_dictionary` is a tibble containing a data dictionary, but this doesn't matter.)

The point is that I want to automate the above code using on a vector `years <- c("2014", "2015", "2017")` so I don't have repeated code.

I try things like

```
for (i in seq_along(years)){
  rename[i] <- glue::glue('eas_dictionary$name', '{i}')
}
```

and

```
for (i in seq_along(years)){
  assign(glue('rename{i}') <- glue('eas_dictionary$name{i}'))
}
```

But these all throw errors.  I'm just not getting a hang of the suntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `lapply` :

```
years <- c("2014", "2015", "2017")
lapply(eas_dictionary[paste0('name', years)], function(x) 
       setNames(x, eas_dictionary$true_name)) -> result

result
```

It is not advised to create multiple individual objects in the environment but if for some reason you need to create them you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you. And @dash2 also pointed out that "Any time you feel tempted to mass assign variable names, use a list instead".